# regex to replace the entire character in string

Tags: regex, finalbuilder

the string may have characters like "abc @ xyz 1234-4321", i need regex to replace the characters inside the quoted string with the another string using text replace action in final builder.

Thanks in advance ,Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Please: sample input, sample expected output and show what your already tried (regex used which does not work for example). Stack Overflow is not a free code service.

Answer (score 0):

".*?" will find anything between two ".

The dot matches everything, while the * tells it that you want somewhere between zero and many occurences. You can then just replace it with "yourstring".

If you don't want to write "yourstring" you could also use a capture group "(.*?)" but honestly it's overkill for this.